# MS Word Interop to C# - Inserting multiple files at a bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have one master document into which I want to insert a number of files. These should be inserted into the file one after another at a certain point in the middle of the document.

So I have created a bookmark at this point called "TESTS", since this seems to be the easiest way of programatically finding the point.

I am able to insert a single file using this code:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(@"C:\master.doc");
 oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>().First(b => b.Name == "TESTS").Range.InsertFile(@"C:\test1.doc");
```

But this removes the bookmark, making it impossible to insert a second file at the same point. I don't mind losing the bookmark, but only once I have inserted all files.

Can this be done? I am guessing that the above code replaces the range with the bookmark so finding the location just before or after and then deleting the bookmark range would be best - but I just can't find the code for it. Everything I have tried seems to replace the whole document.

Alternatively, is there any way to do this without the Interop (i.e. by parsing the file - no touching MS Word at all)?

Comment: I was able to use your code example to do multiple calls of Bookmark("TESTS").Range.InsertFile and it inserted the content from both files as expected.

Comment: Really? I am using the following code: `oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item("TESTS").Range.InsertFile(@"C:\test1.doc"); oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item("TESTS").Range.InsertFile(@"C:\test1.doc");` and it doesn't work the second time. What could cause this difference?

Answer (score 1):

There must be something particular about the way your document is set up and the exact range of the the bookmark because I am able to get this to work without losing the bookmark. According to this MVP article [Inserting text at a bookmark without deleting the bookmark](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/InsertingTextAtBookmark.htm), adding Text to a bookmarked range *should* delete the bookmark; maybe you are running into similar issue with InsertFile.

Try their suggestion of storing the bookmark's range into a variable ie `MyRange` and then calling `Bookmarks.Add "mybookmark", MyRange`

```
Dim BMRange As Range 

Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range 
BMRange.Text = "Hello world" 

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "MyBookmark", BMRange
```