# Write text in Word Document at specific location using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to modify a word document and inserting data at some specific positions( I have a template document which I must get it ready and fill all the blank spaces ).I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library and till now I just figure out how to insert text at the end of the document, I  will write down the code too so maybe someone can help me out.Thanks!

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        string str = null;
        OpenFileDialog dia = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dia.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            str = dia.FileName;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1 = app.Documents.Open(str);

            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            doc1.Content.Text += "Merge?";
            app.Visible = true;
            doc1.Save();
            this.Close();

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Range` object to insert text at a specific position. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.aspx)

```
doc1.Range(0, 0).Text = "Hello World";
```

If you have a template and the position to insert the text is always at the same location, you could also use `Bookmark`. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.bookmark.aspx)

**[Update]**

Here is a complete example to add text to a word document by a bookmark:

```
Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"your file");
string bookmark = "BookmarkName";

Bookmark bm = doc.Bookmarks[bookmark];
Range range = bm.Range;
range.Text = "Hello World";
doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark, range);
```

With this solution, the bookmark will not be deleted and you can add/modify it later again with the same piece of code.

Comment: also there is a way to find the coordinates of each location I want to insert text in? thx

Comment: If the location is always the same, you could add a placeholder in your document and add the text by using the `bookmark` object in c#. See this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad6ks7k0.aspx

Comment: Sorry cause I ask you again but do you know how to delete the text in a bookmark inserted last time?  I mean I insert "some text" first time then the next time I start the program will insert the text "other text" after the text "some text" so it looks like " some text other text"  so how do I delete what I inserted previously in the bookmark?thx

Comment: See this workaround for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624982/delete-contents-of-bookmark-without-deleting-bookmark-in-ms-word-using-c-sharp

Comment: that code is not helping me , I don't know why but the code only delete the first letter of the bookmark so If I write in bookmark "some text" after I use the method to clean bookmark it will only delete first letter so I will have "ome text" instead of having "" ...

Comment: I think you've tried the wrong answer. Have you tried the accepted answer?

Comment: without code it's like looking for a needle in a haystack ;)

Comment: public void cleanBookmark(string bookmark, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1)
        {

              var start = doc1.Bookmarks[bookmark].Start;
              var end = doc1.Bookmarks[bookmark].End;
               Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = doc1.Range(start, end);
               range.Delete();
                doc1.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark, range);
           }

Comment: I added an example to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much Ben for your time .

Answer (score 3):

For sake of simplicity, first add the bookmark in MS Word as follow:

Select the region where you want to add the text, Then go to Insert > Bookmark in Word.

[image]

Then give the name to the bookmark as follow:

[image]

[image]

Then use the follow modified version of Ben:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Report.doc"));

Dictionary<string, string> bookmarks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "DateOfIssue", "23-06-2018"}, { "TotalNumOfPages", "20" } };

foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
{
    Bookmark bm = doc.Bookmarks[bookmark.Key];
    Range range = bm.Range;
    range.Text = bookmark.Value;
    doc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark.Key, range);
}
```

Finally the output is as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to insert a string into another string in a specific position.

```
doc1.Content.Text = doc1.Content.Text.Insert(10, "Merge?");
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx